# Communicating with interactive processes via Ruby popen

Tags: mysql, ruby, telnet, popen

I've been messing around with IO#popen and different programs, and having some trouble with interactive processes.

Here's a stripped down version of the script:

```
def test(command, string)
  IO.popen(command, 'a+') do |pipe|
    puts "Prompt: #{pipe.read(5)}"  # Just to show whether data is read in
    pipe.puts string
  end
end
```

I'm seeing various behavior with a few different interactive processes, and trying to understand why.

```
$ test('pt-kill --user user --ask-pass --print', 'password')
=> This successfully reads in the prompt, and the password is successfully written 
   to the script. Works as desired. (This is a perl script from Percona)

$ test('telnet', 'quit')
=> Blocks indefinitely trying to read the prompt. In the process of hacking around,
   found that calling 'pipe.close_write' prior to the read would allow the read to
   complete. Why?

$ test('mysql -u user -p -e "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL", 'password')
=> Echoes full prompt to the screen, but is still blocking on the first read. 
   Adding a 'pipe.close_write' does nothing.
```

I've been trying to understand the differences, but am at a loss. Anyone have an explanation?